# draw box around every page with column reserved to grades

Tags: exam, border

I want to draw a box around every page of an exam document (exam class)
alongside a rectangle on the left (or right) containing grades as in the figure aside. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: As long at the boxes are outside the text area, there should be no problem.  There are several ways to do this, but the easiest is to use tikzpagenodes and everypage.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426606/exam-class-automatically-print-a-partial-grade-table-on-each-page/426674?r=SearchResults&s=5|23.2193#426674 for example.

Comment: 0

Thanks for the effort. But this is not what i desire to achieve! I want to have exactly as in the picture i attached to my question. Thanks again.